# Upgrade PHP version from 5.5.9 to 5.6

Tags: php

I have installed php5.5.9 and php5.6

but there are two folder named php5 and php in /etc folder

php5 -v gives me version 
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2016 13:00:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

php -v gives
PHP 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

now php point to php version 5.5.9

but i have to point version to 5.6

when i have to try disable php5.5

with  sudo a2dismod php5.5 thi command it gives me error
like

ERROR: Module php5.5 does not exist!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Default php version is 5.6

Comment: no default php version is 5.5.9

Comment: "sudo a2dismod php5.5" for disable php 5.5
"sudo a2enmod php5.6" for enable php 5.6

Comment: solved .. sudo a2dismod php5 and just sudo a2enmod php5.6